# JPA link field value

Tags: jpa

I have three entities, for example `A, B, C`. Entity `A` is parent for `B`, with inheritance type joined. Entity `B` aggregates entity `C` with ManyToOne relationship.
Structure looks like next:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
class A {
    String str;
    String cStr;
}

@Entity
class B extends A {
    @ManyToOne
    C c;
}

@Entity
class C {
    String str;
}
```

I don't know if it is possible at all on entity level but, I need to link value of `str` from `C` to the filed `A.cStr`. How it should looks like: I create entity `B` with populated value of `c`, store it and value from C.str is populating into filed `A.cStr`. And when I fetch A from datebase I can see `A.cStr` with same value as `C.str` has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. All you need to do to get the C string from A is to implement a method and override it in B:

in A:

```
public String getCString() {
    return null;
}
```

in B:

```
@Override
public String getCString() {
    return c.getStr();
}
```

Of course, the instances of A that are not B instances won't have any CString.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. "Of course, the instances of A that are not B instances won't have any CString." completely agree with it, in that case A.str has default value. but it could be overrided with value from C.str if it is instance of B. That is my task.

Comment: But follow your suggestion I can add additional logic into setC in B entity where I could populate A.cStr. So again thank you for your comment, it really helped me.

Comment: Again, you don't need a field in A to do that. Just rely on polymorphism. return `this.str` from `getString()` in A, and override the method in B to return `c.getStr()`.